Login As or similar
I have a set of users who are not admins but perform our UAT testing.

They need to have the ability to "Login As" other users to check what the Sales users of various hierarchy levels are seeing.
I only want them to be able to Login As as selected users.

However I have not granted them the Login As permission since

I do
not want them gaining the Modify All access that comes with it.
I
have not granted them Delegated Admin access as then they must have
Customize Application permission and I do not want want them
modifyingh objects nor do I want them Managing users.

How can I allow
certain users only to have te ability to Login in as certain users
without the added dangerous added access that delegated admin as well
as Login As provides?

I have not granted them Delegated Admin access as then they must have Customize Application permission - this perm is not required for Login As, all you need is View Setup and Configuration - see doc

As I mentioned above , Login As also grants Modify All access which I would not want. Unless there's a workaround to that?
